# Do I have a way to arrange multiple literal lines for displaying without breaking python code indentation?

Tags: python

I am learning python.

I would like to arrange the literal lines for easy code reading and easy outputs reading.
Please see the following code for detail.

```
failed=True
if failed:
    print('\
Failed.\n\
reason:...\n\')
```

Output

```
Failed.
reason:...
```

To arrange the outputs, that is, without no white spaces at the head of lines, literal lines in python code start at the head of lines. However it breaks python code indentation.
 Do I have a way to arrange multiple literal lines for displaying without breaking python code indentation?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in python to have multi-line string you can use triple quotes:

```
failed=True
if failed:
    print('''\
          Failed.\n\
          reason:...\n''')

This will break output indentation:

      Failed.
      reason:...
```

To keep output indentation and code indentation you should append text lines:

```
failed=True
if failed:
    print("Failed.\nreason:...\n")
```

or:

```
print("Failed.\n" +
      "reason:...\n")
```

or:

```
print("Failed.\n"
      "reason:...\n")
```

output:

```
Failed.
reason:...
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not pretty, but you can take advantage of the compiler's nature to concatenate adjacent string literals:

```
print('foo\n'
      'bar\n'
      'baz quux')
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using `textwrap.dedent` together with a triple-quoted string literal. This allows you to freely keep typing your string at whatever indentation level you like and then just close it at the end, which can be easier for a long message:

```
import textwrap
failed=True
if failed:
    print(textwrap.dedent("""\
        Failed.
        reason:...
        you
        entered
        an
        invalid
        number"""))
```

which outputs, with no indentation:

```
Failed.
reason:...
you
entered
an
invalid
number
```

I think this syntax is pretty clean, leaving the overhead entirely to either side of your string, and allowing you to visually maintain the strict indentation.

Answer (score 0):

yes use triple single quotes **'''some text'''** or double quotes  **"""some text"""**.

Here is an example

```
failed=True
if failed:
    print('''\
Failed.\n\
reason:...\n\n''')
```

Comment: How does this solve the indentation issue the asker is concerned with?

Comment: It solves the indenation issue, please run the code and check @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: Yes, the code works, but it still doesn't address the actual issue.

Comment: (The issue being that the code itself is no longer aesthetically indented, as the string literal suddenly jumps to the start of the line)